# Load 1 dataset into select element and filtering searches another endpoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

Here's my select2 component:

```
<select
    multiple
    id="e1" 
    placeholder: "Select meeting participants"
    style="width:450px;"></select>
```

By default, when the page loads, an ajax call is made to load it with a user's contacts.

```
// Roster list remote call + handler =========================================>
transporter.ajax( "/transporter/app/roster/getAll", {}, 
    function( data )
    {
        var contacts = data.response.rlist.contactList;

        for( var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++ )
        {
            var obj = new Object();
            obj[ 'id' ] = i;
            obj[ 'displayName' ] = contacts[i].displayName;
            obj[ 'contactName' ] = contacts[i].contactName;
            obj[ 'contactType' ] = contacts[i].contactType;
            obj[ 'avatar' ] = contacts[i].avatar;
            obj[ 'status' ] = contacts[i].status;

            roster.push( obj );
        }

        var ddl = document.getElementById( 'e1' );

        for ( var j = 0; j < roster.length; j++ ) 
        {
            var o = document.createElement( 'option' );
            o.value = roster[ j ].contactName;
            o.text = roster[ j ].displayName;
            ddl.appendChild( o );                
        }
    });
```

This is what I want to happen: Initial ajax call loads and displays a user's local contact list. It's nice for the user to see and easy for them to select people they often invite for mtgs.

The problem: If they want a user not in their contacts they see a "no matches found" message.

The question: Can the Select2 component then make an ajax call to search a larger directory (at a different endpoint)?

My guess is that it can't and I'll have to add a 2nd Select2 component to do this.

Anyone know the answer?

Thanks for any helpful tips!

Comment: I guess what I'm really trying to find out is can I preload data into my select2 component (the result of the initial ajax call), and then when filtering it searches that local data but also issues an ajax call to search a server-side DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using a query function to test against a local dataset before I make an ajax call to search the directory. Right now I don't have a good filtering function on the local dataset and I make the ajax call whenever the input isn't an empty String.

It's not ideal but it works for now.

```
$( '#e1' ).select2({
                placeholder: "Select participants",
                allowClear:true,
                multiple: true,
                query: function ( query ) 
                {
                    if( query.term == '')
                    {
                        // Query roster list first, if no matches then query directory
                        transporter.ajax( "/transporter/app/roster/getAll", {}, 
                            function( data )
                            {
                                var contacts = data.response.rlist.contactList;
                                var d = { results: [] };

                                for( var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++ )
                                {
                                    var obj = new Object();
                                    obj[ 'id' ] = i;
                                    obj[ 'displayName' ] = contacts[i].displayName;
                                    obj[ 'contactName' ] = contacts[i].contactName;
                                    obj[ 'contactType' ] = contacts[i].contactType;
                                    obj[ 'avatar' ] = contacts[i].avatar;
                                    obj[ 'status' ] = contacts[i].status;

                                    roster.push( obj );

                                    d.results.push( { id:obj.contactName, displayName:obj.displayName, type:0 });
                                }
                                query.callback( d );
                            }
                        );
                    }else{
                        var params = {
                                query:query.term + '*',
                                searchFor:'users',
                                sortBy:'relevance'
                            };

                        // Query directory
                        transporter.ajax( "/transporter/app/search", params, 
                            function( data )
                            {       
                                if( data.response.userList != null )
                                {
                                    if( data.response.userList.user !=  null )
                                    {
                                        var peeps = data.response.userList.user;
                                        var datum = { results: [] };

                                        for( var i = 0; i < peeps.length; i++ )
                                        {
                                            datum.results.push( { id:peeps[ i ].loginName, displayName:peeps[ i ].displayName, type:1 } );
                                        }
                                        query.callback( datum );
                                    }else{
                                        var noResults = { results: [] };
                                        query.callback( noResults );
                                    }
                                }   
                            }
                        );
                    }
                },
                formatResult:formatContacts,
                formatSelection:formatContactsSelection,
                escapeMarkup: function( m ) { return m; }
            });

            function formatContacts( item ) {
                if( item.type != 0 )
                    return item.displayName // + '<br/><a>Add User to Roster</a>';
                else
                    return item.displayName;
            };

            function formatContactsSelection( item ) {
                return item.displayName;
            };
```

Answer (score 2):

Why bother with a second ajax call at all ?

```
/transporter/app/roster/getAll
```

If it returns "no users found" ..you could

1. Don't return "no users found", branch into a more complex search
   right away "second DB like you said", and actually return something
2. if you do want a second ajax call just do something like this

   ```
   transporter.ajax( "/transporter/app/roster/getAll", {}, callBack);

   function callBack( data ) {
       var contacts = data.response.rlist.contactList;

       if (contacts == null || contacts.length == 0) {
           // callback fillList, don't call this in an endless loop
           transporter.ajax( "/transporter/app/roster/searchAll", {}, fillList);

           return;
       }

       fillList( data );
   }

   function fillList( data ) {
       var contacts = data.response.rlist.contactList;

       for( var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++ ) {
           var obj = new Object();
           obj[ 'id' ] = i;
           obj[ 'displayName' ] = contacts[i].displayName;
           obj[ 'contactName' ] = contacts[i].contactName;
           obj[ 'contactType' ] = contacts[i].contactType;
           obj[ 'avatar' ] = contacts[i].avatar;
           obj[ 'status' ] = contacts[i].status;

           roster.push( obj );
       }

       var ddl = document.getElementById( 'e1' );

       for ( var j = 0; j < roster.length; j++ ) {
           var o = document.createElement( 'option' );
           o.value = roster[ j ].contactName;
           o.text = roster[ j ].displayName;
           ddl.appendChild( o );
       }
   }
   ```

I think you actually answered the question yourself

Comment: I'm using a "Select2" component and "no matches found" is the default message returned (when using a <select> element). I'm not sure that I can hook into it to change that.

Comment: I just realized that using a Select2 component won't work at all. I need ajax (to search DB) and a mult-select (so a user can select more than 1 user); Select2 provides one or the other.

Comment: What's a "Select2" component, some third party control ?

Comment: Yes: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/. It's a jquery replacement for select boxes that supports searching and remote data sets. They're very cool but, unfortunately, they support ajax for <input> elements only and multi-select for <select> elements only. I'm looking for a  <select> with ajax support.

Comment: Looks pretty cool, though kinda huge. Why don't you ask someone here https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues You might even get a direct reply from one of the devs

Comment: I just posted directly on the google groups for this component. . I'm sorry, I tried to be clear in my original post that it was regarding a Select2 component.

Comment: Np. I'm pretty sure the component can do what you like since in the examples there is a external-search. Basically you want to switch to external if internal has no results if i understood right.

Comment: Yes, but external search only works with hidden input elements, not select elements. I'm using a select now that allows multiple selections and shows it. An input element, I don't believe, allows that.It's important because I want to be able to show all contacts a user has chosen (and give them the opportunity to delete them). That's the nice part about these Select2 mult-select components.